# Python: access structure field through its name in a string

Tags: python, ip, structure, field, scapy

In Scapy, I want to compare a number of header fields between any two packets `a` and `b`. This list of fields is predefined, say:

```
fieldsToCompare = ['tos', 'id', 'len', 'proto'] #IP header
```

Normally I would do it individually:

```
if a[IP].tos == b[IP].tos:
   ... do stuff...
```

Is there any way to access those packet fields from a list of strings including what each one of them is called? Like:

```
for field in fieldsToCompare:
    if a[IP].field == b[IP].field:
         ... do stuff...
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). These lines are equivalent:

```
getattr(x, 'foobar')
x.foobar
```

[`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) is its counterpart.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for `getattr()`. Try...

```
for field in fieldsToCompare:
    if getattr(a[IP], field) == getattr(b[IP], field):
         ... do stuff...
```