# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) in python

Tags: python, opencv, augmented-reality, aruco

I am working with OpenCV ArUco in Python. I am trying to generate multiple codes of different directories. To generate it in a single time I am using this function in a loop. For example list1 =[1,2,3,4],comb = [50,100,250,1000],ids = [1,22,3,45]

```
def generator(bsize,comb,ids):

    bitsize = [bsize]+['X']+[bsize]
    bitz = ''.join(bitsize)

    dicts = ['DICT']+[bitz]+[comb]
    dictionary = '_'.join(dicts)
    print(dictionary)

    path = ['aruco']+[dictionary]
    print(path)
    path = '.'.join(path)
    print(path)

    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(path)
    img = aruco.drawMarker(aruco_dict, ids, bsize)
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)

for i in range(0,7):
    generator(list1[i],list2[i],list3[i])
```

the output of 'path' is:

```
aruco.DICT_4X4_1000
```

after that I am getting error:

```
line 35, in generator
aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(path)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

How do I resolve this error. Please help

Comment: how were the parameters "given"? the error message seems clear, somewhere the code is getting a string where it expected an integer. there is a difference between '3' and 3 for example.

Comment: you will need to post more of your traceback for us to understand.. maybe edit your question and post your full traceback?

Comment: As I can understand, `Dictionary_get()` takes int parameter. `join()` method on strings return a string. In your case that is getting stored in `path` variable, finally you are passing that string to `Dictionary_get()`. Just check parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"aruco.DICT_4X4_1000"`, a string, is different from `aruco.DICT_4X4_1000`, an attribute in `aruco`.

If you want to programmatically access `aruco`'s value for the attribute `DICT_4X4_1000`, you [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060625/python-access-structure-field-through-its-name-in-a-string):

```
getattr(aruco, "DICT_4X4_1000")
```

So your code for getting `path` should be:

```
...
path = getattr(aruco, dictionary)
...
```

Comment: Yay! Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it is the best solution to the problem in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see at http://www.philipzucker.com/aruco-in-opencv/, `aruco.DICT_6X6_250` is real constant (int). In your can it is a string `"aruco.DICT_6X6_250"` and this is main reason of error. For clarification, just try the below 2 statements in place of `path = '.'.join(path)`.

- Valid

  `path = aruco.DICT_4X4_1000`
- Invalid

  `path = "aruco.DICT_4X4_1000"`

> You'll find, the 2nd one is responsible for error.

My suggestion to fix this kind of issue is to create any module named **arcuo_constants.py** and place the contents like below in that.

> arcuo_constants.py

```
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco

# define all possible constants here
ARUCO_CONSTANTS = {
    "aruco.DICT_6X6_250": aruco.DICT_6X6_250,
    "aruco.DICT_4X4_1000": aruco.DICT_4X4_1000
}
```

And finally in your code file, you can import and use those values as follows (Let suppose module file is in the same directory).

```
import aruco_constants

ARUCO_CONSTANTS = aruco_constants.ARUCO_CONSTANTS # A dictionary
# ...
# ...
path = '.'.join(path)
path = ARUCO_CONSTANTS[path]
aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(path)
# ...
# ...
```